# jquery-free-transform + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

i'm having trouble getting https://github.com/gthmb/jquery-free-transform and AngularJS working well. The controls for scale and rotate aren't getting the width/height of the attached element.I am using a directive to attach jQuery.freetrans() to my dynamic generated element.

```
<div ng-class="layout.element" freetrans></div>
```

```
app.directive('freetrans', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.freetrans();
         }
    };
});
```

the class name is e.g. "image". It works well if i use

```
<div class="image" freetrans></div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="{{ layout.element }}" freetrans></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-class="layout.element" freetrans></div>
```

hope, anybody could help me.

Thanks & Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see it seems that you are calling the elem.freetrans() before the class is attached or the element is rendered in the DOM.

There are 2 things you can try:

1. Use $timeout(function () {elem.freetrans()}) - you would sometimes need a $timeout in a directive to do something with the element after it has been rendered in the DOM (for e.g. get it's with/height);
2. Use attrs.$observe to make sure the class is set when you try to call elem.freetrans().

Comment: Thanks a lot! `attrs.$observe('ngClass', function() { elem.freetrans(); });` did work for me! :)